# Bibliography style: aunsrt

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I tried to use style: `aunsrt` ([sample](http://www.mackichan.com/products/shells/aunsrt.pdf)) or `aunsnot` ([sample](http://www.mackichan.com/products/shells/aunsnot.pdf)) but both do not work. I have an error message about undefined control sequences. Other standard styles work. Do you know what I am doing wrong? Maybe I should add some packages?

I just used following command to add it:

```
\bibliographystyle{aunsrt}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you point to a source for `aunsrt.bst`? Can you show a minimal example of code that fails?

Comment: Hi! ;) well I just found website where all styles are listed and I picked one, here is a link : http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?techtalk/632.htm~mainFrame

Comment: I have added picture of error message. Thanks for response!

Comment: I can only see pdf files linked on that page. It seems to be about scientific wordplace, commercial software. Since nobody can answer the question in its current state, i vote to close as unclear.